# AOP and Exception issues in Controller Layer

Tags: java, spring, controller, aop

Our application has the following layers and interaction:

View (JSP) -> Ajax calls -> MyController (implements Spring Controller) ->  through a custom service lookup -> MyService (implements Base Service) -> My DAOimpl

Our idea is to use AOP for logging exceptions. To keep the AOP intercepts simple, we decided to define the cuts on the Controllers. The Controllers have a few methods like onLoad, onUpdate (related to CRUD ops) which are called from the handleRequest method, and we would like to define these methods for the poitncut.
Ie., any exception at the Service layer or below, will bubble up and will reach the Controllers. AOP pointcut defined to intercept the throws exception and log the exception details into a log. Subsequently, an error code will be sent back to the view where the error message will be displayed appropriately.

Issues: 
-   AOP does not intercept the calls to  the onLoad, etc methods. We understand that this is because calls to these methods from handleRequest are treated as self calls on the Controller and hence AOP does not intercept them. 
-   To circumvent the issue above, we created an interface with onLoad, onUpdate methods and a set of util classes that implement the onLoad, etc methods. The Controllers will have these utils as members. Pointcuts will be defined on these utils instead of the Controllers. When doing this, AOP works only if the AOP config is present in the spring-servlet xml and not in a custom xml for AOP declaration. This observation is only for Controllers. If the AOP cuts are defined on Service layer, then the declarations work as expected (in a custom xml). We are not sure of the dependency between spring servlet xml and the cuts on Controllers.

Suggestions required:
-   Should we have AOP defined for Controllers at all? Should this be defined only at Service layer? At the Controllers, the exceptions will be ‘caught’ and the error message will be sent to view appropriately. Wanted to check if there are any fundamental issues in the original approach.

Comment: Hint: If you use real AspectJ AOP instead of Spring Proxy AOP you would be able to intercept even the invocations from the same instance (`this.onLoad()`).

Answer (score 0):

We do something similar in our product where we catch exceptions at the Service layer and do translation. There are two aspects to this translation. One is of course to do with I18N. The other translation is to make sure that no low level exceptions are making it out of the product. Instead, such exceptions are converted to a generic exception thus preventing exception leaks.

I think that catching Exceptions at Service layer is a good practice because that leaves lower layers free from exception handling (if they choose not to). More over, it gives us a chance to do translation and/or any other actions.

Thanks,
Raghu